# Does making a HEAD request still require the 3 way handshake?

Tags: http, python-requests, http-headers, httprequest

I'm making an http request in my code and I am curious if making a HEAD request still makes the syn, syn-ack, and ack? I've never heard of HEAD until now.

Comment: It is treated like all the other requests, but when you request `HEAD` method, you receive only the header, so you need the 3 way handshake, unless if you want to get an error in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Does making a HEAD request still require the 3 way handshake?"*

It depends. `HEAD` request is a concept in HTTP, the application layer; while "3 way handshake" is a concept in TCP, the transport layer.

Thus, whether `HEAD` request requires "3 way handshake" depends on whether it is using TCP. For HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, the answer is yes. For HTTP/3, the answer is no, as HTTP/3 is based on UDP.